# How can I change the type of a field in a linked model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models: the first is called 'PurchaseList', it includes a field, called 'recipe'. The field 'recipe' is a ForeignKey for building up the link to the second model, called 'Recipe' by creating a new field called 'is_in_shopping_cart':

```
class PurchaseList(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey('User',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               verbose_name='Автор',
                               related_name='added_to_cart')
    recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipe',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               verbose_name='Рецепт',
                               related_name='is_in_shopping_cart')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Список покупок'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Списки покупок'
        ordering = ['recipes']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recipe


class Recipe(models.Model):

    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, verbose_name='Теги')
    author = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='recipes',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор')
    ingridients = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='IngredientToRecipe',
                                         verbose_name='Ингредиент')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name='Наименование')
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='recipes/images/',
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Изображение'
    )
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание')
    cooking_time = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='Время приготовления в минутах')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                    verbose_name='Дата публикации')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Рецепт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Рецепты'
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My target is to make the field 'is_in_shopping_cart' a BooleanField. So the question is how to determine the type of a field formed from a related model in the main model.

I've found this way of solving the problem:

```
@property
def is_in_shopping_cart(self):  
    return PurchaseList.objects.filter(author=self.author).exists()
```

But i'm not sure if it works.

Moreover, my friend advised me to try include attribute called 'field' to the field 'recipe' and put the type 'BooleanField' there, but I haven't found anything about this attribute in the documentation, so I don't know, how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether a Recipe object is associated with a PurchaseList, you can implement a method in your Recipe model like this:

**Using Related Name**

```
@property
def is_in_shopping_cart(self):
    return self.is_in_shopping_cart.exists()
```

Alternatively, you can use a direct query approach, like you did. However, keep in mind that every time you call this method, it will make a database query.

Using the related name can be more efficient, especially if the related objects are already prefetched using select_related or prefetch_related.

Comment: I think, this is not the thing, that i'm trying to get.
The documentation tells, that the field `is_in_shopping_cart` must be boolean. I have just added it to the model `Recipe` through putting the `related_name` to the field `recipe` in the model `PurchaseList`. My target is to make it appear as a BooleanField in the `Recipe` model.